# On saving entity PrimaryGeneratedColumn value not generated, gives NOT NULL constraint error

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, typeorm

Typeorm 0.2.8

I'm building an Ionic app for both mobile use and browser (PWA) use. Below is some shortened code from my project. I create a simple entity with a `PrimaryGeneratedColumn` and try to insert one instance. This generates an error about the primary column being `NULL`. Doesn't the word 'generated' mean the column value gets generated?

Is this a bug? Something specific to the `sqljs` driver? Or something obvious and simple I missed?

#### Entity

```
@Entity()
export class MyEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id:number;

    @Column()
    name:string;

    @CreateDateColumn()
    createdAt:string;
}
```

#### Migration

```
export class Migration20181022133900 implements MigrationInterface {

    async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
        await queryRunner.createTable(new Table({
            name: 'my_entity',
            columns: [
                {
                    name: 'id',
                    type: 'int',
                    isPrimary: true,
                    isGenerated: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'name',
                    type: 'varchar'
                },
                {
                    name: 'createdAt',
                    type: 'timestamp',
                    'default': 'now()'
                }
            ]
        }), true);
    }

    async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
        await queryRunner.dropTable('my_entity');
    }
}
```

#### Database provider

```
const DATABASE_SHARED_OPTIONS:Partial<ConnectionOptions> = {
    entities: [
        MyEntity
    ],
    logging: 'all',
    logger: new DatabaseLogger(),
    migrationsRun: true,
    migrations: [
        Migration20181022133900
    ]
};
@Injectable()
export class Database {

    constructor(public platform:Platform) {}

    setup(): Promise<Connection> {
        let options: CordovaConnectionOptions | SqljsConnectionOptions;

        // Mobile app
        if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
            options = {
                type: 'cordova',
                database: 'my_project.db',
                location: 'default',
            };
            options = Object.assign(options, DATABASE_SHARED_OPTIONS);
        }

        // Browser PWA app
        else {
            options = {
                type: 'sqljs',
                autoSave: true,
                location: 'my_project',
            };
            options = Object.assign(options, DATABASE_SHARED_OPTIONS);
        }

        return createConnection(options);
    }
}
```

#### App component

```
export class MyApp {

    constructor(
        platform: Platform,
        database: Database
    ) {
      platform.ready().then(() => {
        database.setup()
            .then((connection) => {
                  this.insertTest();
            });
      });
    }

    insertTest() {
        const myEntity= new MyEntity();
        myEntity.name = 'foo';
        getRepository(MyEntity).save(myEntity)
            .then((data) => {
                  console.log(data); // never reached due to error
            });
    }
}
```

The database log show the following query (with parameters `["foo"]`):

```
INSERT INTO "my_entity"("name", "createdAt") VALUES (?, datetime('now'))
```

The following error shows up in my console:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): QueryFailedError: NOT NULL constraint failed: my_entity.id
```

#### Update 1

It only seems to give the error when using migrations. Removing the migrations and using `synchronize: true` on the database setting works and generates an `id` for the entity. So is there something wrong with my column definition in the migration code?

```
{
    name: 'id',
    type: 'int',
    isPrimary: true,
    isGenerated: true
}
```

#### Update 2

Okay, I fixed it. The migration configuration for a `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn` seems to be very specific. For anyone else facing this issue, this fixed it for me:

```
{
    name: 'id',
    type: 'integer', // instead of 'int', required for the increment strategy
    isPrimary: true,
    isGenerated: true,
    generationStrategy: 'increment' // thought this was the default
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I fixed it. The migration configuration for a `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn` seems to be very specific. For anyone else facing this issue, this fixed it for me:

```
{
    name: 'id',
    type: 'integer', // instead of 'int', required for the increment strategy
    isPrimary: true,
    isGenerated: true,
    generationStrategy: 'increment' // thought this was the default
}
```